How to change select option value while loading dropdown>?
I have long text for each item but I want to set substring the value for the text while loading the select dropdown.
I tried this but not working.
  <select class="form-control chosen-select" id="eventCode" name="eventCode" >
  @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Events)
  {
      <option value="getEventCode(@item)">@item</option>
  }

script
 <script type="text/javascript">
    
function getEventCode(eventCodeStr) {

    let eventCode = eventCodeStr.substring(0, eventCodeStr.indexOf("("));
    alet(eventCode);
    return eventCode;
}
</script>

text example is this 18AA10 (Smarter Well Integrity 5/7/2018) and I need to get value 18AA10. How to do this?

What framework are you using that supports all the @ stuff in your code? That's not HTML or JavaScript.

It probably should be @getEventCode(item). You can't put function calls inside value, it's just literal text.

What is the issue? Is it updating the select element with option elements or getting a substring of a string?

You are probably using asp.net or c#. So better is to manipulate the string on the server.
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Events)
{
    int index = item.IndexOf('(');
    string modifiedItem = index!= -1 ? item.Substring(0, index) : item;
    <option value="@modifiedItem">@modifiedItem</option>
}

